# Can Twisted be used as an interface between web/http and UDP?

Tags: http, udp, twisted

I have a network device that speaks UDP.  I want to develop a web front end for it.  Can I use twisted to implement an API that will then send a UDP packet, wait for a reply, and then display the response to the web client?

I believe I can start/run a UDP and Web application at the same time, but I'm not sure how to get them to talk to each other.  Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This sort of integration is exactly what Twisted is for. Just make a https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.web.server.Site.html and then call https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorUDP.html#listenUDP with your UDP listener, and everything should work more or less out of the box.

In terms of getting them to talk to each other — they're both python objects.  Just instantiate them with a reference to whatever data they need; maybe even a reference to each other, if you must.  This is why all the objects within Twisted take a Factory of some kind. Give your web server a Resource object that references your UDP server, and vice versa.